# Switchable Voltage Divider

Tags: mosfet, voltage-divider

To provide an adjustable, switchable reference voltage to the xVREF input (Iref -3uA to 3uA) of the current control of a [DRV8825](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8825.pdf) stepper motor driver allowing to reduce power during stand still, I tried the following circuit:

[image: Switchable voltage divider]

As expected, I can for example switch between 1V and 260mV allowing to reduce motor current from 1A to about a quarter, still being able to adjust the current.

I'm just unsure if this is a good design?

Comment: That would entirely depend on what you're connecting it to.

Comment: Resistor is never a good idea for voltage or current limiters. You can look for voltage and/or current regulators.

Comment: @ozgur A resistor based voltage or current limiting circuit is perfectly fine for thousands of applications. To say it "is never a good idea" is weak minded and wrong. Think again.

Comment: @Asmyldof it is connected to xVREF of a DRV8825, I updated my question

Comment: @ozgur the divider provides ref voltage for a current regulator

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain?

Comment: @TorstenRömer I don't know why I didn't see the symbol. You are right.

Comment: "I'm just unsure if this is a good design?"  Why did you put a question mark at the end of a declarative statement?

Comment: @JRE in this rhetorical question, I wanted to assert that I think it is a good design because it works as expected. I'm just not sure about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a perfectly fine way to do it. Note that the effect of the 7.5k on the 100k variable resistor will depend on the actual setting of that R.